# kendo grid is not filtered properly

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid,and treeview with checkboxes in my application.I want to filter the grid based on treeview checkbox selection,i tried this one but its not working properly
my treeview code is

```
    $("#treeview").on("change", function (e) {
   var ds = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
    ds.filter([
    {"logic":"or",
     "filters":[
         {
            "field":"OrderId",
            "operator":"eq",
             }
     ]}    ]);
  });
```

my fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/66/

Answer (score 1):

In treeview on change event you need to catch the checked nodes,and then filter the grid datasource based on your condition with field,operator and value of the treeview selected node.

```
 $("#treeview").on("change", function (e) {
    var selected = $('#treeview :checked').closest('li');
    var ds = grid.dataSource;
    var filter = {
        logic  : "or",
        filters: []
    };
```

This is the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/RHh67/87/

Cheers,
Happy coding